# Bot framework 412 "The data is change" when connect with Luis

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a simple bot with help of Luis. It's very basic code and I don't know why I get 412 error after I past message to Luis intent. My code look like:

MessageController:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{
    // Get any saved values
    StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
    await sc.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId,activity.From.Id);

    var haveGreeting = userData.GetProperty<bool>("HaveGreeting");
    // Create text for a reply message   
    StringBuilder strReplyMessage = new StringBuilder();
    if (haveGreeting == false)
    {
        strReplyMessage.Append($"Hi, how are you today?");
        userData.SetProperty("HaveGreeting", true);
    }
    else
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MeBotLuisDialog());
    }

    // Save BotUserData
    var botaData = await sc.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId,
        activity.From.Id, userData);
    // Create a reply message
    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
    Activity replyMessage = activity.CreateReply(strReplyMessage.ToString());
    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
}
```

Luis intent:

```
[LuisIntent("HowAreYou")]
public async Task HowAreYou(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Great! Thank for asking");
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Is this failing in the emulator?

Comment: No, I have publish this bot for testing but still get this issue

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860020/microsoft-bot-framework-exception-the-data-is-changed/42913460#42913460

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Bot Framework: Exception: The data is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860020/microsoft-bot-framework-exception-the-data-is-changed)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code in your `Global.asax.cs` file

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(c.Resolve<ConnectorStore>(), CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.LastWriteWins))
    .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

And please, review the relevant technical FAQs around this issue:

- [What is an ETag? How does it relate to bot data bag storage?](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#what-is-an-etag--how-does-it-relate-to-bot-data-bag-storage)
- [What causes “precondition failed” (412) or “conflict” (409) HTTP errors?](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#what-causes-precondition-failed-412-or-conflict-409-http-errors)
- [How can I fix “precondition failed” (412) or “conflict” (409) HTTP errors?](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#how-can-i-fix-precondition-failed-412-or-conflict-409-http-errors)