# BotFramework save userData 412 error

Tags: botframework

I want to save data in the activity state userdata to use it later in the conversation.

The problem is that every time I save the userdata, I've got an error that said :

```
 Exception: The data is changed
```

Code to save the data :

```
public static void saveCategorieName(Activity activity, string key, List value)
{
      StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
      BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
      userData.SetProperty>(key, value);
      BotData updateResponse = stateClient.BotState.SetUserData(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
}
```

I save multiple times the data, so I want to overwrite the userdata with the same key, the problem could be this.

Edit : The data inside the userData is saved correctly but I still got this message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967003/bot-framework-412-the-data-is-change-when-connect-with-luis

Comment: Already tried that, and it doesn't work for me

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860020/microsoft-bot-framework-exception-the-data-is-changed